# Redirection of error page with aspx and mspx extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, web-config

I have a webforms website in which I have to custom the errors page so I put this snippet in my web.config

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom"   >
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/france/Errors/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
      <error statusCode="500" path="/france/Errors/Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
```

The problem is that if the page not found's extension is ".aspx" or ".mspx" : I get the default page error of IIS!!! I mean it is not handled by the application .

**Example**

> notfound.html ==> redirection to Error.aspx
>
> notfound.asp ==> redirection to Error.aspx
>
> notfound.aspx ==> Default IIS error page

So I need to know :

1. What is the reason of this problem? Do I forgot some property to set?
2. How can I fix it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information on [Ted Gustaf's blog](https://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/custom-404-and-error-pages-for-asp-net-and-static-files/), I solved my problem by replacing my code with:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
     <clear />
     <error statusCode="404" path="/france/Errors/Error.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
     <error statusCode="500" path="/france/Errors/Error.aspx" responseMode="Redirect"/>
   </httpErrors>
```